# Hidden scrollbar unless page resize

Tags: jquery, html, scrollbar, mcustomscrollbar

I need a custom scrollbar plugin for a personal project (by "custom" I mean basic inertia effects, custom images and so on). My choice was [mCustomScrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller).

The documentation was indeed very clear, and I haven't had any trouble implementing the script, but it seems to work only when I resize the page, as if scrolling isn't needed.

In fact, the scrollbar has `style="display: hidden"` on a fully loaded page, like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370179/scrollbar-automatically-hidden-unless-i-resize-the-page) (but I couldn't find any useful answers).

I believe there's some `height` issue linked with `slidesjs` (which I'm using as well), but I just can't find it...here's some code:

([There's](http://canteletermoidraulica.com/preview/prodotti.html) the whole page, so you can view the code with firebug...just go under "Pulcini" to view the long content)

```
<head>
  <!-- everything is included -->
  <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="css/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function(){
      $("#slides").slides({
        generatePagination: false,
        pagination: true,
        paginationClass: 'pagination'
      });
    });
  </script>
  <script>
    (function($){
      $(window).load(function(){
        $("#slide2").mCustomScrollbar();
      });
    })(jQuery);
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="slides">
    <!-- other stuff -->
    <div class="slides_container">
      <div id="slide1">
        <h2>Uova</h2>
        <p>Text1...</p>
      </div>
      <!-- slide2 is the scrollbar div -->
      <div id="slide2">
        <h2>Blabla</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum</p><br />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
div#slides {
  height: 506px;
}
.slides_container {
  width: 900px;
  height: 506px;
}

.slides_container, div#slide1, div#slide2, div#slide3, {
  width: 808px;
  height: 366px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.slides_container {
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  height: 366px;
}​
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had same problem. So I changed the fluid code for `updateOnBrowserResize: true`, and  `updateOnContentResize: true`, and now it works great with all the javascript.

```js
(function($) {  
  $(window).load(function() {  
    $("#content_1").mCustomScrollbar({  
      scrollEasing:"easeOutCirc",  
      mouseWheel:"auto",   
      autoDraggerLength:true,   
      advanced:{  
        updateOnBrowserResize:true,   
        updateOnContentResize:true   
      } // removed extra commas  
    });  
  });  
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: This is by far the best solution I've seen.  The option that corrected this issue for me was:                                            `advanced: { updateOnContentResize : true }`

Answer (score 3):

You're initializing the mCustomScrollbar while the container its in is still hidden, so the browser can't calculate the height of the div.  You'll need to either trigger a resize event when the div becomes visible, or do not initialize the scrollbar until it first becomes active on the page.

Answer (score 0):

http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

this is very nice link for custom scroll bar I also use this plug-in in my projects you can easily customized it and nested scroll bars are also available here.